# 90s retelling of Twelfth Night set in Internet chatrooms

Tags: identification-request

I'm looking for a book I read in the late 1990s that actually was the inspiration for the username I still use today.

- It was based on the plot of Shakespeare's Twelfth Night, with people falling in love while not knowing one another's true gender identities.
- These people met in chatrooms in the very early days of the Internet (think "a/s/l").
- The Shakespeare character Sebastian was named Serenthia in this re-telling.
- I don't remember it being... high quality fiction and I think it was quite short.
- I assume I read it in physical format, but I don't recall anything about its appearance.
- I once met someone else online who cited the same inspiration for their username (not all serenthias are me!) and they also read it in the UK.
- It was written in English (not translated from another language).

Many thanks, detectives!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a short novel which seems to meet much of your description, Published in 1998, [*Love Online* by Lisa Tuttle](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RyNhBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT2&dq=%22lisa%20Tuttle%22%20Love%20online&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjt1--pkoPyAhUPgVwKHaS3DHMQ6AEwAnoECAoQAg#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> When Rose moves to America to stay with her grandmother, the internet enables her to keep in touch with her family and play games in multi-user domains.
>
> She meets Orson, Olivia and Simon in the ‘domain’ of Illyria, where they become people they are not and find a deeper truth in fantasy.

From what I can see from Google Books, Rose takes on two characters in the domain of Illyria, Serenthia and Roberto.

Comment: It was actually pretty easy to find with the information you gave. I literally just searched 'Serenthia' in Google books and excluded World of Warcraft and Diablo from the search. I had it in about 3 minutes.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered going directly to Google Books - was using just Google Search which returned too much.  Good tip, thank you :-)